# Customer login error magento2

Tags: magento2, customer, login, customer-account

> I have used reset password and changed the password.

When try to login with the new password i changed from the forgot password link.

Getting below error.

```
You did not sign in correctly or your account is temporarily disabled.
```

I have entered correct password.

Before reset password also same error i was getting. Has anyone faced the same issue?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you have admin panel access of the Magento 2 store, then you can try to reset the password again from backend and you will get a password reset email.
Also you can try Force Sign-In features from Admin panel.

For more information,
Please see this link https://docs.magento.com/m2/2.0/ee/user_guide/customers/customer-password-reset.html

Thank you

Comment: hi @Pritam, i have reset my password successfully, that is not my issue

Comment: As suggested from the link, i tried force-sign in from admin panel, after that i am getting error like This customer has no tokens.