# Customer save after event magento2

Tags: magento2, event-observer, adminhtml, customer-account

I have used this event "**customer_save_after_data_object**"

used this code in events.xml file

```
<event name="customer_save_after_data_object">
    <observer name="customer_save_after_observer" instance="Vendor\Sales\Observer\CustomereditPost" />
</event>
```

And this is the observer file

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
class CustomereditPost implements ObserverInterface

    {
        protected $_request;
        protected $_layout;
        protected $_objectManager = null;
        protected $_customerGroup;
        private $logger;
        protected $_customerRepositoryInterface;

    /**
    * @param \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
    */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface
    ){
        $this->_layout = $context->getLayout();
        $this->_request = $context->getRequest();
        $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->_customerRepositoryInterface = $customerRepositoryInterface;
    }

    /**
    * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
    * @return void
    */
    public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {
        $this->logger->info(' --jafar123--  ');
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $customer = $observer->getCustomerDataObject();
        $customer->getId();
        $customer->getFirstName();
        $customerId = $customer->getId();
        $customerData = $this->_customerRepositoryInterface->getById($customerId);
        $customerData->setFirstName('jaf');
        $customerData->save();
        return $this;
    }
}
```

On saving customer from admin panel, I need to trigger this file.

Just setting the customer first name from this event. But the name is not changed.

The observer file is loading. Can anybody help me on this please?

Comment: have you checked that after saving customer from admin panel ,logs are print in var/log folder or not? i means control comes in your observer file or not?

Comment: Yes, it is coming to observer file, and it is printed to log file

Comment: then  put this field also in $customer->getId();
    $customer->getFirstName(); and check what value comes in this log

Comment: @balwant, yes i am getting those values.

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**update your code with below code and try**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
class CustomereditPost implements ObserverInterface
{
protected $_request;
protected $_layout;
protected $_objectManager = null;
protected $_customerGroup;
private $logger;
protected $_customerRepositoryInterface;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
    \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface
){
    $this->_layout = $context->getLayout();
    $this->_request = $context->getRequest();
    $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
    $this->logger = $logger;
    $this->_customerRepositoryInterface = $customerRepositoryInterface;
}

/**
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
 * @return void
 */
public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
{
    $this->logger->info(' --jafar123--  ');
    $event = $observer->getEvent();
    $customer = $observer->getCustomerDataObject();
    $customerId = $customer->getId();
    $customer->getFirstName();
    $customerData = $this->_customerRepositoryInterface->getById($customerId);
    $customerData->setFirstName('jaf');
    $customerData->save();
    return $this;
}
}
```

Comment: hi @balwant, call to undefined method save().

Comment: @jafarpinjar try my updated answer

Comment: can you look into this please https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/251094/customer-login-error-magento2/251100#251100

Comment: @jafarpinjar welcome..!!! happy coding :)

Comment: can you help on the other issue @balwant

Comment: hi, @Balwant, sorry, the code didn't work for me. getting below error, Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer::save()

Comment: @jafarpinjar, how can be possible this? that time you told it's  working..okay if you are saying it's not working then add your code here.

Comment: i checked in other instance, thought its worked sorry,updated the question now

Comment: @jafarpinjar no need to be sorry. it's okay..can you plz add your updated code here? so i can check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86167/discussion-between-jafar-pinjar-and-balwant-singh).