# How to create an event-observer that will help print a log when admin modifies some customer details?

Tags: event-observer, customer, magento2.3

I want to design an event and an observer that will print a separate log containing the details of the fields that was modified by the admin in admin panel (under all Customers -> edit). How can I achieve this?

Comment: I have just found this module free. I tried it as well works fine.https://github.com/kiwicommerce/magento2-admin-activity
it stores all changes made by admin.

Comment: But I didnt find the solution to my problem there. I checked the specifications mentioned

Comment: Actually this module stores all changes made by admin to customer account. I tested it it works. It will also give facility to revert changes which is done by admin.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Customer save after event magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/251105/customer-save-after-event-magento2)

Comment: I have to print the modified fields only; in the log. How can it be done?