# What is the event that will fire after assigning customer to group in Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, customer, adminhtml, customer-group

I have to fire an observer method when the admin assign customer(s) to group on adminhtml. Can you help me which event is it?

I tried `adminhtml_customer_save_after` but it didn't worked.

**Edit:**
My config.xml

```
    <adminhtml>
        <events>
            <adminhtml_customer_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <vendorname_packagename_customerconfigobserve>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Vendor_Package_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>observeCustomerConfig</method>
                    </vendorname_packagename_customerconfigobserve>
                </observers>
            </adminhtml_customer_save_after>
        </events>
    </adminhtml>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below event

Magento 2 :-

```
<event name="customer_save_after_data_object">
    <observer name="customer_save_after_observer" instance="Vendor\Sales\Observer\CustomereditPost" />
</event>
```

Magento 1 : -

```
<config>
    <adminhtml>
        <events>
            <adminhtml_customer_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <My_WebService_customer_register_success>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>My_WebService_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>customerRegisterSuccess</method>
                    </My_WebService_customer_register_success>
                </observers>
            </adminhtml_customer_save_after>
        </events>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/251105/customer-save-after-event-magento2 check this one

Comment: This might work in Magento2, but sadly this is a Magento1.9 store. Can you know what event should I use in 1.9?

Comment: check it i have update my code

Comment: You have to call the event inside the adminhtml, not inside global

Comment: It didn't triggered my method

Comment: please show me your event config code or update in your question

Comment: I added it as an update